# VB.NET with phpmyadmin server, how to delete records in table every after end of the day?

Tags: vb.net, phpmyadmin

I want to delete the data in all tables at the end of the day.
Below is my sample code, can you help me, please?

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_attendance WHERE emp_date"

    Dim DATEIN As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Dim delete As String = "DELETE FROM `tbl_attendance` WHERE 0"
    Try
        If query <> DATEIN Then
            con.Open()
            Dim mysc As New MySqlCommand(delete, con)
            mysc.ExecuteNonQuery()


        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(“Data Deleted!”)
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "System Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

Comment: Typically, questions here require a little bit more work.  An expiation of how code doesn't meet requirements, details of exceptions etc.  On topic, are you sure about the Where clause on your delete SQL?  Seems a bit off, if you are just clearing all rows from the table, leave the where off

Comment: Deleting records and performing a task at a specific time are two separate, unrelated problems. Does your code successfully delete the intended records? If so then that part isn't actually the problem, so isn't really relevant. Either your issue is deleting records or it's performing a task on schedule. It cannot be both for the purposes of an SO question. If you are having issues with both then you need to post two separate questions, each focusing on one specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not VB related but I assume that you are using MySQL so if you want to delete data every end of the day I advice you to directly add an event in your MySQL. This is how to create an event using MySQL.

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER DEFINER=`usr`@`%` EVENT `call_counter` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND STARTS '2019-09-17 05:46:05' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `tbl_attendance` /*WHERE clause goes here*/;
    
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The event will do the deletion for you.

Make sure to set the **event_scheduler** to ON.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  "ON"
```